# Where are SQL Server linked server located and is it one linked server per database?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I'm looking at SQL Server linked servers and want to understand is the linked server a logical concept based on configuration files or a physical implementation and does it reside on the same server as the database?

Also, is it one linked server per database or can multiple databases share the same linked server?

Thanks

Comment: No to all. A Linked server is a *completely separate remote service or product* that can accept queries from the local database. It may be an Oracle or MySQL database for example. SQL Server sends the query string, or at least part of it, to the remote server, retrieves the results and combines them with the local data. There's no magic or indexing involved though. If you try to JOIN with a remote table SQL Server may try to retrieve all rows, spool them in tempdb and JOIN them locally

Comment: linked server definitions are at SQL Server Instance level and refer to a complete different server. you can see the it's details at [sys.servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-servers-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) system view

Comment: Whether there are one or more databases in the linked server is up to that server, its configuration and even what is meant by "database" there. In Oracle for example the equivalent to a database is a schema while an Oracle database is actually a server instance.

Answer (score 2):

Linked servers are configured at instance level and aren't related to a single databases.

They are a way to access relational databases (not only SQL Server) that are defined on other instances/servers, so they doesn't store data by itself but are only a definition that tell SQL Server how to access to the external resources.

You could use linked servers to perform queries against this external resources, and eventually join this data with local tables & views (there are many performance implications related to the access to external resources, so pay attention on how you define the queries).

For an overview on linked servers see [Linked Servers (Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) for detailed information.

Comment: Good answer, although you can even access non-relational / non-databases like Excel/Access, as long as they support the linked server provider